# Open an URL with an opened frame with google app script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I want to open an URL with google apps script when I click a button.

Here is my code:

```
function testNew(){
  showAnchor('Ticket','http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/ajuda');
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

However, I want to open a page that contains a frame. The frame is a form that is opened at the right side of the web page when I click "Fale Conosco".

My goal is to open the web page with the frame altogether so that I can copy a chunk of text into the form. So that I do not need to click "Fale Conosco" every time. The thing is that I don't know how to find the URL with the frame.

Is there any way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `My goal is to open the web page with the frame altogether so that I can copy a chunk of text into the form. So that I do not need to click "Fale Conosco" every time. The thing is that I don't know how to find the URL with the frame.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tainake So.. If I open the URL (www.mercadolivre.com/ajuda) directly, the frame is not there. I need to click a link at the bottom of the page called Fale Conosco", so that the frame appears". What I want to do is to open the URL with the frame there as if I had already clicked the link

Comment: @user3284182 You need to know "how" clicking "Fale Conosco" opens the iframe?  Is there a anchor link there? Is there a click handler? Depending on how the link creates the iframe, it may or may not be possible to achieve your end goal.

Comment: @TheMaster , I do not know. How can I know this? Inspecting the page?

Comment: @user3284182 ````yes````